# PHP Associative Array use variable as a key

Tags: php

I want to "map" values obtained from an excel file.

If `$row['type']` contained '**TYPE ONE**' I would expect to get '**value-one**'. But instead, I get an error.

I don't know if that's just not how associative arrays work in PHP.

```
$arrType = [
  'TYPE ONE' => 'value-one',
  'TYPE TWO' => 'value-two',
];
$key = $row['type'];

echo $arrType[$key]; //Error Undefined index: TYPE ONE
```

If I manually assign the string value... it works...

```
$arrType = [
  'TYPE ONE' => 'value-one',
  'TYPE TWO' => 'value-two',
];
$key = 'TYPE ONE';

echo $arrType[$key]; //value-one
```

**EDIT 27 Aug 2021**
It works on production. For the time, we will leave it like that... We think the problem is excel encoding or something...

**EDIT 14 Sep 2021**
It was an issue with special characters. It worked on production but still, some regex was used to remove them.

$type = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', '', implode(str_split($arrType[$key])));

echo $arrType[$type]; //Expected value

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Undefined index: TYPE ONE

Comment: This obviously means that value of `$row['type']` is not what you expect. `var_dump($row['type'])`

Comment: Try casting as string `$key = (string)$row['type']`

Comment: I'm ussing xdebug to see the values... if i do $row['type'] it shows "TYPE ONE"

Comment: Althoug it is a laravel collection obtained from an excel file... maybe that's the issue

Comment: Already tried casting to string

Comment: Does your value contains quotes? Can you please try ```$key = trim($row['type'], '"');```?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséOviedoJuárez Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump($row, $arrType);` to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with special characters. It worked on production but still, some regex was used to remove them.

```php
$type = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', '', implode(str_split($arrType[$key])));

echo $arrType[$type]; //Expected value
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider

```
    $row = [
    'TYPE'=>'TYPE TWO',
    'type'=>'TYPE ONE ' //possible spaces -- use trim()
    ];

    $arrType = [
        'TYPE ONE' => 'value-one',
        'TYPE TWO' => 'value-two',
    ];

    $key = $row['type'];
    echo $arrType[$key]; //Notice: Undefined index: TYPE ONE

    $key = trim($row['type']);
    echo $arrType[$key]; //value-one
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but already tried trimming and casting.